# Como agregar un mismo objeto a espacios diferentes en un arreglo JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Para un trabajo necesito simular una memoria RAM, para ello le he pedido al usuario programas iniciales y secundarios tomando en cuenta el nombre, espacio que ocupa y el tiempo que lo estará ejecutando.

Ahora bien, hasta ahora he logrado conseguir toda la información necesaria, sin embargo no logro agregar los programas a la cantidad de espacios que necesitan.

Por ejemplo, si tengo un programa llamado programa1 que ocupa 75, al agregarlo al arreglo de RAM necesita ocupar un espacio x y otro espacio x+1 (cada espacio en el arreglo RAM corresponde a 64 Mb teoricamente)

Sin embargo, no logro hacerlo de esa manera, no logro agregar por ejemplo un mismo elemento a mas de un espacio dependiendo del espacio que ocupa. ¿Alguien me podria ayudar? comparto mi codigo para que puedan darse una idea

```
//se crea un nuevo arreglo general en donde se guardaran todos los programas
ArrayList<Memoria> general = new ArrayList<Memoria>();

//se recorrera el arreglo de programas iniciales y se agregaran al general
int posicion_general1 = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<programas_iniciales_4gb.size();i++){
    general.add(posicion_general1, programas_iniciales_4gb.get(i));
    posicion_general1++;
}

//Se recorrera el arreglo de programas secundarios y se agregaran al general
for(int i = 0;i<programas_secundarios4gb.size();i++){
    general.add(posicion_general1, programas_secundarios4gb.get(i));
}

//una vez se tenga el arreglo general completo, se crea un arreglo para la memoria RAM y otro para los programas en cola
ArrayList<Memoria> ramsdr4 = new ArrayList<Memoria>();
ArrayList<Memoria> colasdr4 = new ArrayList<Memoria>();

//se agregaran a la ram todos los programas en el arreglo general, hasta que tenga un tamanio de 64 bloques de memoria

int bloque_memoria = 64;//representa el valor de Mb que tiene de capacidad un bloque de memoria
int capacidad_total = 64;//representa la cantidad de bloques que tiene esta memoria RAM

//se hara un bucle que recorra el arreglo general y vaya agregando como corresponde, este bucle para cuando la ram haya alcanzado su capacidad maxima. 64 bloques de memoria
do{
    //se recorre el arreglo general para determinar el valor de espacio de cada programa
    //si el arreglo general, en la posicion i tiene un espacio igual que...
    for(int i = 0;i<general.size();i++){
        //un bloque de memoria
        if(bloque_memoria == general.get(i).getEspacio()){
            //el elemento del arreglo de general se agrega a un espacio del arreglo ramsdr4
            ramsdr4.add(i, general.get(i));
        }
        if(2*bloque_memoria == general.get(i).getEspacio()){
            //dos bloques de memoria
            ramsdr4.add(i, general.get(i));
            ramsdr4.add(i+1, general.get(i));

        }
    }
```

Comment: No se si te entendí bien, tienes 64 bloques de 64MB lo que quieres es insertar un programa en cada bloque consecutivamente; Lo que no mencionas o no se entiende es si un programa tiene longitud mayor a 64 MB digamos 75 MB entonces ocupara 1 bloque de 64 MB y otro bloque de 11 MB; **Mi Pregunta es** el bloque restante donde ocupa los 11 MB lo ocupará otro programa o va quedar vacío los 53 MB restantes?. Siento que falta varias explicaciones también me gustaría saber el comportamiento de ``programas_iniciales_4gb`` y ``programas_secundarios4gb``

Answer (score 0):

**Lo podrías hacer agregando la siguiente validación en tu bloque do (Cambio los if por else if para que el programa realice menos validaciones):**

```
                do{
                    //se recorre el arreglo general para determinar el valor de espacio de cada programa
                    //si el arreglo general, en la posicion i tiene un espacio igual que...
                    for(int i = 0;i<general.size();i++){
                        //un bloque de memoria
                        if(bloque_memoria == general.get(i).getEspacio()){
                            //el elemento del arreglo de general se agrega a un espacio del arreglo ramsdr4
                            ramsdr4.add(i, general.get(i));
                        } else if (2*bloque_memoria == general.get(i).getEspacio()){
                            //dos bloques de memoria
                            ramsdr4.add(i, general.get(i));
                            ramsdr4.add((i+1), general.get(i));

                        } else if (bloque_memoria < general.get(i).getEspacio()){
                            //el elemento del arreglo de general se agrega a un espacio del arreglo ramsdr4
                            ramsdr4.add(i, general.get(i));
                            ramsdr4.add((i+1), general.get(i));
                            i++;
                            
                        }
                    }
```

**Sugerencia:**

1. Podrías eliminar la variable posicion_general1 y de ese modo usar                     general.add(i, programas_iniciales_4gb.get(i)); dejando el código de la sgt. manera:

```
//se recorrera el arreglo de programas iniciales y se agregaran al general

for (int i = 0;i<programas_iniciales_4gb.size();i++){
    general.add(posicion_general1, programas_iniciales_4gb.get(i));
}
```

2. Se están agregando todos los elementos de programas_secundarios4gb.get(i) en la misma posición, porque en todo el transcurso de ejecución del for, posicion_general1 tiene el mismo valor, también lo podrías cambiar por i:

```
//Se recorrera el arreglo de programas secundarios y se agregaran al general
for (int i = 0;i<programas_secundarios4gb.size();i++){
    general.add(i, programas_secundarios4gb.get(i));
}
```